# Usage of the word "ascetic"

Tags: grammaticality, phrases

Is the sentence "You have to be ascetic about eating junk food" correct?

**Ascetic:** Practicing severe self-denial

Comment: Ascetic is more commonly used as a substantive --> *he is an ascetic* than in reference to particular things one does not do. Consequently, I would probably not use the word ascetic to express your point which I take to be *you have to be disciplined about not eating junk food*

Comment: @virmaior Your comment is the best answer. Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

an [*ascetic*](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+ascetic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=sb) is one who is characterized by the practice of severe self-discipline and abstention from **all** forms of indulgence, typically for religious reasons.

> an ascetic life of prayer, fasting, and manual labor

The word denotes and connotes a lifestyle, not individual choices here and there inclined toward sacrifice.

As such, *You have to be ascetic about eating junk food* is a misuse, as it is a choice to eat healthfully, not to meditate, sleep on stone slabs, pray, work and eat less than one wants to.

Comment: Knowing this, how could the word "ascetically" be used in a sentence?

Comment: His decision to live ascetically bewildered his wealthy relatives. ?

Comment: It's not just wrong as far as definition. It's also wrong grammar. I like your answer, but it's missing the crucial component of why a word like "ascetic" *cannot* be used in the example sentence.

Answer (score 3):

It's grammatically fine, but the meaning of *ascetic* is much stronger than someone who would never eat junk food. An ascetic wouldn't eat much food at all, abstain from sex, and generally forgo most or all material comforts.

As such, you can't really be ascetic about eating junk food, or to the extent that you can, you would just use the expression, "never ever eat junk food".

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you can practice severe self-denial *while* eating. There's even an [idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Have_one%27s_cake_and_eat_it_too),

> Would you both eat your cake, and have your cake?

Comment: Good link, thanks. Hard to believe that idiom has been around for 500 years... Makes me feel young. :)

Comment: @Susan It just proves that my problem with junk food is hardly new!

Answer (score 1):

You're using it kinda verbishly, where common use is more noun or adjective.

Examples that sound better to me (western usa, fwiw):

> "Jane's an ascetic. She doesn't eat junk food."
>
> "Ascetics abstain from junk food."
>
> "Extreme fasting is part of our monastery's ascetic practice."
>
> "Asceticism is the practice of rigorous self-denial, typically as a spiritual discipline."

Others have mentioned that your use is wrong because it implies asceticism is casual. While yes, asceticism is defined in terms of harsh self-denial, it's the least problematic thing about your sentence. My first example is similar to your malformed sentence, and I feel it invokes humour by insinuating something as deep as asceticism could be achieved by simply avoiding junk food.